# How do I add a variable to a piece of text?

Tags: construct-2

I am creating a side scroller game, and I want a counter on the UI that counts how many times the player has died. But, I do not know what to add to what I have already. I tried typing the variable name behind the &, but it did not accept that. What do I do to put a variable in a set of text?

[image]

I am using the free version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` is the string concatenation operator in Construct 2.

For global variables:

```
"Deaths: " & VARIABLE_NAME
```

For instance variables:

```
"Deaths: " & instanceName.variableName
```

Note the `"` around the string.

*NB: There is no need to explicitly convert the number to a string, it will be done implicitly.*

Comment: variable_name? So in my case, it would be variable_deaths?

Comment: Yes, I _think_ you just type it.

Comment: @ShadowZ. You might need to convert the variable to a string, as per above.

Comment: I will test it when i get back to my computer.

Comment: Just checked it myself, no need to convert the number to a string, it is indeed done implicitly.

Comment: I think I might be messing up somewhere else. Where would I create the instance variable? I created it under the text object properties. Would I have to put it somewhere else?

Comment: One thing: Would it be related to the fact I am using the free version?

Comment: No, I use the free version.  Is it an instance variable?  If so, it is `"text" & instance_name.instance_variable`.

Answer (score -2):

Construct-2 runs on Javascript, so would the "+" operator not do what you are attempting?

Comment: I switched it to +, and then put the variable after it, but Construct 2 told me that there is no expression or variable with that name in this scope. I am wondering if I need to relocate my variable to somewhere else instead of an instance varaible under the Text properties.

Comment: Construct 2 produces JavaScript, it doesn't run on it.